# Question regarding continuity

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is the following proposition true: let $f(x,y)$ be a real valued function such that $f(x,y)=c$, where $c$ is a constant. If $f(x,y)$ is continuous in $x$ then it is continuous in $y$.

Comment: Is $f$ constant?

Comment: What does "continuous in $x$" mean?

Comment: Constant functions are continuous.

Comment: @wj32 $∀y∈ℝ:\, x ↦ f(x,y)$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

1. Constant functions are continuous in whatever variables they have.
2. If $B$ is a true statement, then the statement "if $A$ then $B$" is also true, regardless of what $A$ says.
3. Therefore,  "If $f(x,y)$ is continuous in $x$ then it is continuous in $y$." is true.